# Gaussian measure push-forward through linear partial differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

**Setup**

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary and $\zeta \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ be distributed according to a Gaussian measure such that $\zeta \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathcal{C}_\zeta)$ where $\mathcal{C}_\zeta$ is the covariance operator. Using the Karhunen-Loeve expansion, we can write 
$$
\zeta = \sum_k \lambda_k^{1/2}\eta_k\phi_k
$$
where $\{\lambda_k,\phi_k\}$ are the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $\mathcal{C}_\zeta$ (self-adjoint, trace-class operator) and $\eta_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is independent and identically distributed.

Now let $A_\zeta := I-\Delta + \zeta\nabla$ be a linear p.d. operator with domain $D_A = C^2_c(\Omega)$, parameterized by the random field $\zeta$. For example, if I am thinking right, the following holds for the expectation
$$\mathbb{E}(A_\zeta) = I-\Delta.
$$

---

**Question**

What I am trying to figure out, is a formula for the Gaussian measure that describes the range of $A_\zeta$, $\text{Ran}(A_\zeta)$. That is, if
$$A_\zeta x = y \quad,\quad y \in C_c(\Omega)$$
defines a linear PDE (assume zero-Dirichlet boundary conditions), then $x = A_\zeta^{-1}y$ and there must be a Gaussian measure $\mu = \mathcal{N}(m,\mathcal{C})$, with mean $m$ and covariance operator $\mathcal{C}$ such that
$$
x \sim \mu
$$
Thus, in the end, we should be able to express $x$ via the K-L expansion as before and write
$$
x = m + \sum_k \lambda_k^{1/2}\eta_k\phi_k
$$
where $\{\lambda_k,\phi_k\}$ are now the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $\mathcal{C}$.

---

**Note**

For a numerical approximation of the above, one could sample $\zeta$ using the K-L expansion, and compute the corresponding $x$ by solving the linear PDE in order to estimate the measure $\mu$. However, since this problem is linear I think I should be able to find a formula for the covariance operator $\mathcal{C}$.

---

Any ideas how I could formulate that?

Fixing $y \in C_c(\Omega)$, this is as far as I can get right now...

**mean**

$$
m = \mathbb{E}[x] = \mathbb{E}[A_\zeta^{-1}]y = (I-\Delta)^{-1}y \quad \text{since} \quad \mathbb{E}[\zeta] \equiv 0 \quad \text{(zero function)}
$$

**covariance op.**

$$
\mathcal{C} = \mathbb{E}[(x-m)(x-m)^*] = \mathbb{E}[xx^*] - mm^* = \mathbb{E}[A_\zeta^{-1}xx^*(A_\zeta^{-1})^*] - mm^*
$$

Does that seem correct?

I guess we would like to make the covariance operator $\mathcal{C}_\zeta := \mathbb{E}[\zeta\zeta^*]$ appear, but this inversion does not permit that right now.

Comment: I'm wondering from the Note you make, can't you just assume for the moment that $x,\zeta$ and $y$ have the same eigenfunctions and $\eta_k$ but different eigenvalues, plug the expansions in your linear SPDE and compute $m$ and $\lambda_k$ for $x$ in terms of the $\lambda_k$ of $\zeta$ and $y$? Then you can maybe work you way back to write it in terms of $C_\zeta$?

Comment: @C.Hamster Yes, I am doing this for special cases: when $A_\zeta$ is, for example, self-adjoint. Then you end up with a formula for the mean and the covariance that depends on new (weighted) eigenvalues and transformed eigenfunctions. To assume that all operators ($A_\zeta,\ \mathcal{C}_\zeta$ etc.) share the same eigenfunctions is usually unrealistic and not interesting for practical applications. Maybe assuming that there is such a basis for each operator then you can jump from one orthonormal basis to another by a slightly more complicated formula (involving projections back and forth).

Comment: @C.Hamster I guess what you're proposing is the simplest way to proceed further when $A^{-1}_\zeta,(A^{-1}_\zeta)^*$ appear... I was wondering if there is an other way though.